# "edit" trigger does not activate when altering Google Sheets via mobile app

Tags: mobile, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Im trying to move a row from one sheet to another using a script.

The problem: i'm using a phone app as the input to the spreadsheet, but for some reason it doesn't activate the "edit" trigger?

Here is my script:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "Sheet1" && r.getColumn() == 14 && r.getValue() == "Finished") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Finished");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to make your question a bit easier to read by rewording and improving the code indentation. Please review my changes if they meet your intent.

Comment: Does it work on a desktop? Simple triggers, like `onEdit`, need to be authorized before they can access particular classes or methods.

Comment: Yes, it does work when it is entered normally from a desktop.

Comment: Yes,TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 3, file "Code")

Comment: That makes sense. If the problem is that the script is not "seeing" the edit from the mobile app. Could i use a time trigger every minute to check for "Finished" in the column? Im not sure how to do that.

Comment: @|'-'| My apologies. yes i also viewed it on the Executions, it showed it failed.

Comment: @I'-'I When i use the app, it does not show as an execution in the list.